# upgrade the license for a user from E1 to E3

Tags: office-365, administration, licensing

I have one user who have the E1 license as follow:-

[image]

but i need to grant this user E3 license .. how i can do so? as i can not find any option to do the upgrade?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Purchase the E3 license as you would any other license, then assign the E3 license to the end user as you would assign any other license. You can, if you wish, then cancel the E1 license subscription.

Comment: so you mean i need to but a new E3 license, i thought that there is a way to upgrade the license so i only pay for the differences between E1 & E3 .

Comment: You may be able to do that through a reseller (or technically an EA with MSFT), but I've never heard of pro-rating M365 subscriptions.